# Get element from a column python

Tags: python

I need to extract column from a table and compare each element of this column with number 5. I am getting a list of element from the column but it shows an empty output in console.

```
def compare():
    with open('table.csv') as csv_file:
        lines = csv_file.readlines()
        for line in lines[1::]:
            array = line.split(',')
            list_pk = array[1]
        if list_pk == "5":
            print("Match")
```

Comment: where do you get error and what error is it? Can you provide an example of file input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a first glance of your code, your if statement should be inside the for loop for it to print anything unless you get lucky and last line has a match:

```
def compare():
    with open('table.csv') as csv_file:
        lines = csv_file.readlines()
        for line in lines[1::]:
            array = line.split(',')
            list_pk = array[1]
            if list_pk == 5:
                print("Match")
```